# C# Regex is replacing more than expected

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm on .NET5 with EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.8

I have an SQL script that I'm reading in as an embedded resource. However, executing it directly as is is proving to be difficult. It's being read in like this.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = N'MyTrigger' AND [type] = 'TR')\r\nBEGIN\r\n      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger];\r\nEND;\r\nGO\r\n\r\nCREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger] \r\n   ON  [dbo].[MyTable]\r\n   AFTER INSERT\r\nAS \r\nBEGIN\r\n\t--DECLARE @Cinfo VARBINARY(128) \r\n\t--SELECT @Cinfo = Context_Info() \r\n\t--IF @Cinfo = 0x55555 \r\n\t--RETURN \r\n\t-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from\r\n\t-- interfering with SELECT statements.\r\n\tSET NOCOUNT ON;\r\n\tDECLARE @O AS INT\r\n\tDECLARE @D AS INT\r\n\tDECLARE @A AS REAL\r\n\tDECLARE @N AS REAL\r\n\tSET @O = (SELECT TOP 1 OtherId FROM inserted)\r\n\t ... (Removed for breveity) GO
```

And the c# code to read and run this looks like,

```
List<string> resourceNames = new List<string> {"MyTrigger.sql" };
        
try {
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    resourceNames.ForEach(resourceName => {
        string script = ReadEmbeddedResource(resourceName);
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(script); // Exception thrown here
    });
} finally {
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

This however is yielding the following error,

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll: 'Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.'
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at MyLib.MyService.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<MigrateScripts>b__0(String resourceName) in
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the way the script is being executed, so my plan of attack is as follows,

1. Remove all comments
2. Replace all new lines, carriage returns, and tabs with spaces
3. Split the script off of "GO"
4. Run each individual section of the SQL script as a separate transaction

The code I've written for this is as follows,

```
List<string> resourceNames = new List<string> {"MyTrigger.sql" };

DbContext context = GetDbContext(contextType);
try {
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    resourceNames.ForEach(resourceName => {
        string script = ReadEmbeddedResource(resourceName);
        // remove comments 
        script = Regex.Replace(script, "[-][-][^\\\\]*\\r\\n", " "); // <- This line is removing too much
        // remove new lines and tabs 
        script = Regex.Replace(script, "\\.", " ");
        // split by GOs and run each section independently
        List<string> scriptParts = Regex.Split(script, "GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToList();
        scriptParts.ForEach(scriptPart => context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(scriptPart));
        
    });
} finally {
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

After running `script = Regex.Replace(script, "[-][-][^\\\\]*\\r\\n", " ");` however, the script looks like,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = N'MyTrigger' AND [type] = 'TR')\r\nBEGIN\r\n      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger];\r\nEND;\r\nGO\r\n\r\nCREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger] \r\n   ON  [dbo].[MyTable]\r\n   AFTER INSERT\r\nAS \r\nBEGIN\r\n\t GO
```

I.E. it's removing everything after the first comment inside of the Create Trigger script. I'd like it to remove just the comments and nothing else. Each comment in the script starts with "--" and ends with "\r\n".

The Regex for this is based off of `--[^\\]*\\r\\n`, which I've tested in VSCode's find and replace, as well as this site: https://www.regextester.com/. It seems to be working correctly in both.

So my question is why is this regex in C# replacing more than I'm expecting it to, and how can I update it to get the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my plan of attack is as follows,

> 1. Remove all comments
> 2. Replace all new lines, carriage returns, and tabs with spaces
> 3. Split the script off of "GO"

I'd *start* by splitting on `GO`. C# SqlCommand doesn't care about comments, whitespace etc and the parser in SQLS will discard them anyway so your 1. and 2. are making work for no reason.. This would execute fine:

```
var c = new SqlCommand(@"/* Rhett wrote it */
SELECT name --just need name for now
FROM   t");
```

`GO` however is a "sql server management studio" thing for splitting scripts into batches and should not be sent to sql server

---

As to your question, possibly youre misunderstanding how `*` works. It's greedy, so it consumes the entire input then spits characters back out if the match didn't succeed

This means that

```
the.*o
```

When used on

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yeah!
```

Matches this:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yeah!
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Not this:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yeah!
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because it finds "the", then consumes the entire string, and spits back out looking for a match:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yeah! - NO MATCH, ends in !, looking for o
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yeah  - NO MATCH, ends in h, looking for o
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yea   - NO MATCH, ends in a, looking for o
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, ye    ...
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, y
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, 
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog        - NO MATCH, ends in g, looking for o
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy do         - MATCH
```

If you want a regex to crawl forwards looking for the first chance to make a match, put `?` after the `*`

```
the.*?o
```

Matches:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yeah!
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, for light bathroom reading, check out the MultiLine and SingleLine regex options, which affect how `.` handles newline chars, and what `$`/`^` consider to be the start/end of input